# RESTful API sorting dilemma

Tags: architecture, sorting, rest

I have REST API implemented following the principle that rest just gives back the basic documents and refs in those documents howto get other things etc etc

For example a /car/5    will give me  model:blabla , user_id: 1  and then if you need the owner you'll get /user/1 to get user data..

This way JOINS and stuff are avoided in DB..all things are linking between themselves and data interconnected on rest client part - keeping things simple easy to cache/drop cache, scale etc.

But what happens when you need sorting?

Imagine we have some view on frontend to display following data:
Car model, User name, etc... and you wanna sort by user name for example.

You can't really tell the   /car/5   to sort by username cause it only knows of user ids...

One option I see is sorting from user /user/list?sortby=username and then interconnecting which of those returned ids actually refer to car.   but this means we need to get ALL users..and only use fraction of those which seems killer performance bottleneck.

Thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 6):

I think you're trying to avoid joining for all the wrong reasons, as by taking this approach, you're going to have to service a lot more requests.

If you instead bring back all the information that you'd show (i.e. do the joins database side), then the clients are going to have to make less queries, and you *could* do your sort without having to (lazy) load all the child objects.

The other option would be to bring back the children objects as child XML elements (in a similar manner to how OpenStreetMap's RESTful interface works). You still have a single hit from the client, and you should be able to optimise the queries to minimise load on the DB.

Answer (score 5):

If you are avoiding all joins in the server and leaving it up to the client then in this case you must leave sorting to the client too. This is because a join has to take place in order to sort the cars by Username.

You can create another resource called CarsAndOwners or similar which returns the joined list, at which point it becomes reasonable to sort on the server.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, your example `/car/5` should be the plural version of the resource in order to be RESTful:

```
/cars/5
/users/1
```

Now, in general if you want a RESTful approach to sorting you can do this:

```
/cars?sort=make&order=asc
```

In your example, you mention that you want to sort cars by username. However, like you mention, the `cars` collection should know nothing about `users`. So if you want to display a list of cars and group them by user, what do you do? You need a way to retrieve this information. One way of doing this is to loop through the users and request the cars associated with each user:

```
# pseudo code

users.each do |user|
  # assuming the user id is 5,
  # to display the user's cars, 
  # we need to request /users/5/cars
end
```

So we can request the list of cars for each individual at a URL like `/users/5/cars`. This is known as a nested resource. We are only requesting the cars that are related to user 5.

However, then you have the issue of potentially making lots of requests to your API (which may be okay depending on your use case).

Another approach, which is probably better, is to do this in one request to:

```
/users/cars?sort=username&order=asc
```

This would return an array of users and their cars ordered by username.

And yet another approach could be:

```
/users?include=[cars]&sort=username&order=asc
```

but I dont like this approach as much as the previous. I would recommend the previous approach of `/users/cars`.

Side note: your lists should be paginated so that there is not the overhead of requesting *all* of the `users` when you are only displaying a partial list.

```
/users?page=1&per_page=50
```

Comment: Plural resource naming is not a requirement of REST -- what is a requirement is uniform semantics for affordances for every resource: meaning, every exposed resource should behave the same way (from the consumer's perspective) to the available protocol methods (GET, POST, DELETE, etc...)

Answer (score 4):

I'd start by imagining the ideal RESTful query that I'd like to write, for instance:

```
/car/list?sortby=username
```

And then figure out how to implement that.

Now your *list* method gives you *car* objects that don't expose *username* as you said, but I don't think that matters.  All the sorting should take place on the server before the list is prepared.

You are going to need to join your *car* objects to *user* objects at some point in order to do this, and there's no way of dodging that issue.  The only choice you have is where you do it.

If you are working with a traditional RDBMS it makes sense to do that at the DB level.

---

Are you using an ORM layer between your application API and the database?

Comment: well all persistance is behind the REST..currently rest is using ORM but I don't think this is relevant.

Comment: I got the hint that you were using ORM because you said that you were avoiding joins on the DB, and connecting all your objects in the REST application layer.

I can see the attractiveness of this simple clean architecture, but it's probably at the root of your current dilemma.

I'd be looking to compromise this architecture in order to get the application working: having additional stored procs or views on the DB that return the data pre-sorted, still providing ORM mapping for these objects, and letting the REST application pick between methods depending on the query.

Answer (score 2):

Databases are designed to do joins quickly, so leaving it up to the client or your server application does not make sense to me.

Almost everything I've read on REST says that relationships between entities/resources should be a resource also. Therefore you should have a resource /mydomain.com/CarsAndUsers that represents that join/relationship.

Then you can do sorting on that resource just like any other, and it will be handled by the database:

/mydomain.com/CarsAndUsers?sortby=username

You can also apply filtering to that resource (and paging) just like any other resource.

EDIT:

As per the comments it would be better to do something like this:

> /cars?embed=user,sortby=username

Thanks Eric for pointing this out.

Comment: That's a recipe for combinatorial explosion of API endpoints. A more common RESTful approach is to use parameters to request inlined objects (essentially joined representations). For example: `/albums?embed=artist`. Those resources available for embedding can have links in a hypermedia `links` collection to make the option discoverable.

Comment: Thanks Eric, whilst I agree with your point about explosion of endpoints, the question is not about related objects but about sorting one set based on the property of a related set. I am not sure what you are suggesting solves that particular issue. Or are you saying that the OP could do this:
 /cars?embed=user,sortby=username

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much exactly what I'm suggesting.

Comment: @EricElliott Thanks for confirming and yes, you are right, that's a better approach. I will edit my answer.